# Determine highest .NET Framework version

Tags: .net, c++, c, version-detection

I need to determine the highest .NET framework version installed on a desktop machine from C\C++ code.  Looks like I can iterate the folders under `%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework`, but that seems kind of error prone.  Is there a better way?  Perhaps a registry key I can inspect?  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [Windows Registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) location `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP`.

Comment: Yes, HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP should be a little easier. Looks like I'll have to iterate the subkeys and then query the Version value. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Registry keys for the .NET Framework start like this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\
```

Depending on the version, the rest of the key will be different (check [this page](http://www.walkernews.net/2007/07/30/how-to-verify-dot-net-framework-version/)).

You can look up how to access the registry in MSDN article *[Using the registry in a C++ application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838625.aspx)*.

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to do this from managed code, take a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/frameworkversiondetection.aspx), which wraps all of the logic needed to determine if a specific Framework version is installed.

Otherwise, take a look at Aaron's blog post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2007/11/29/6608419.aspx), which gives a C/C++ method for doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The following is supposed to give you the answer, but it seems horribly broken :(

```
c:\Program Files>clrver
Versions installed on the machine:
v2.0.50727
```

Comment: The CLR version is not necessarily the same as the .Net version.  .Net v2.0 updated the CLR over v1.1, but .Net v3.0 & v3.5 did not change the CLR, so it remains "V2.0.50727"