# where can I lookup if I am running .net 3.5 or 3.5 sp1?

Tags: .net

I want to verify if a computer is running .net 3.5 or 3.5 sp1, where do I look this info up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP
```

This topic has been covered here:
 [Determine highest .NET Framework version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182910/determine-highest-net-framework-version#182935)

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer [here](http://www.walkernews.net/2008/05/16/how-to-check-net-framework-version-installed/).

Comment: Why did you remove the part on "How i found it" ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a fast answer without a lot of work, you could go to http://www.smallestdotnet.com/ in IE, and it will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Open VS if you have it, click help and click about. it should tell you the .net version, VS version and other addins.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Visual Stuido.